# Why does type inference only work with a pipe here?

Tags: f#

I have a piece of code like this:

```ml
let! deliveries = 
  async {
    match Option.map (fun x -> x.Address) maybeUser with
    | Some "" -> return []
    | Some address -> return! fetchDeliveries address
    | None -> return []
  }
```

The type inference on this fails at `x.Address`.

However, if I reorder the code with a pipe it works:

```ml
let! deliveries = 
  async {
    match maybeUser |> Option.map (fun x -> x.Address) with
    | Some "" -> return []
    | Some address -> return! fetchDeliveries address
    | None -> return []
  }
```

Why is this?

Comment: Note that `Option.map (fun x -> x.Address) maybeUser` still works as long as the module containing the `User` type opened and there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because F#'s compiler is a single-pass, top-down, left-to-right compiler. So when typechecking a file, any type information from the left of an expression is able to be used to verify the right.  The reason why the `|>` example works is because the left-hand side has a definite type (in this case some kind of `User option` type that you've defined, which tells `Option.map` that yes the  item coming in is an `User option`, so the lambda function you pass in must be of type `User -> something else`, which of course it is.